# Can we publish a SQL Server CE database to sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sql-server-ce, publish

I have created a VB NET application that stores data in a SQL Server CE database. Now, I want others to be able to extract data from this database.

Can I host it on Sharepoint site? If yes, how can I do that? If No, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the data you want to publish and weather or not it can be built into a view. If you have it stored on the SharePoint server you should be able to create a BDCS Connection to it and publish the view as an External Content type.

If you need multiple views to access the data, then you will need multiple external content types (these can be built from the one BDCS Connection)

Alternativly, you could create a WCF service that returns the data from the SQL Server CE database, this can then be connected to via BDCS to again display the information through an external content type.

there are a few options (all through BDCS, so I would recommend using that as a starting point), you just need to work out what is best for you